# Как вывести текст на 1 строке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

Изучаю Python. Не знаю как вывести это на 1 строку. Если не сложно объясните как это сделать.

```
while True:
    print("Это тест на знание материала") + input("Вы готовы?")
    break
```

Comment: Непонятно о чём речь, `input("Это тест на знание материала. Вы готовы?")` что ли?

Comment: `print("Это тест на знание материала. ", end=' '); input("Вы готовы? ")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Ответ есть в комментариях к вопросу: я поясню подробнее, что происходит*

> `print("Это тест на знание материала. ", end=' '); input("Вы готовы? ")`

Функция `print()` может принять на вход как один аргумент в виде строки `"Это тест на знание материала. "`, так и второй аргумент, привязанный к определенному параметру, который есть у этой функции. У функции print прописан параметр `end`, характеризующий символ, на который заканчивается выводимая строка, по умолчанию он равен `\n`.

Таким образом следующие вызовы абсолютно эквивалентны:

```py
print("Это тест на знание материала. ", end='\n')
print("Это тест на знание материала. ")
```

Вы можете присвоить значение параметру `end`, чтобы выводимая строка кончалась на иной символ. Автор указал пробел, но на мой взгляд в этом случае лучше всего подойдёт пустой символ `end=''`.